# Looking for a better way to make JLabel fade in/out

Tags: java, user-interface, jlabel, fadein, alpha

Right now I have this (just increasing the label's alpha with small breaks in between):

```
            ae.getErrorLabel().setVisible(true);
            ae.getErrorLabel().setForeground(new Color(255, 0, 0, 0));
            ae.getErrorLabel().setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
            int alpha = 0;
            while (alpha < 255) {
                // wait-Methode
                long time0, time1;
                time0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                do {
                    time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                } while ((time1 - time0) < 0.1 * 1000);
                // =====================================
                alpha += 25;
                if (alpha > 255)
                    alpha = 255;
                ae.getErrorLabel().setForeground(
                        new Color(255, 0, 0, alpha));
                ae.getErrorLabel().setBackground(
                        new Color(128, 128, 128, alpha));
```

This makes the JLabel "fade in".
But it looks kind of buggy and not really nice to look at.
Is there a better way to do it (which is not too complicated)?

Btw: It is swing, a simple JLabel on a smiple JPanel, I use this code in a separate thread that is run when you press a button

Comment: Are you using javafx ?

Comment: @TomJ Oh sorry should've stated that.
No I use Swing, would it be better if I used it?

Comment: Swing is fine, not bad. But in my opinion javafx is much more advanced. If you wish to use swing, use it. Are you using any IDE like  netbeans or eclipse ?

Comment: @TomJ Yes I use Eclipse.
I haven't worked with JavaFX yet, only used something from it to play mp3-files in a Swing frame.
But maybe I should have a look at it

Comment: If you don't worked with it, then it will be better to use swing because it will take some time for you to understand javafx. But it is not tough to understand. If you have time you can try javafx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Animation is not an easy thing to implement correctly. For this reason **is it better to use a tested library. One of the best is Trident.** Here are related links:

https://kenai.com/projects/trident/pages/Home

https://github.com/kirillcool/trident

Comment: This looks interesting, I guess I'll accept this as the answer